# What to include in a Festschrift (memorial publication)?

Tags: writing, professor-emeritus

A now deceased professor would have turned 100 year this year. What is the best way to honor his achievements?

Should a Festschrift (memorial publication) include:

- Personal anecdotes on how you first met his thoughts in university
- Personal reflections on what his thoughts has meant for your career further on in life
- Review of publications
- Links to others reviews of his publications
- A detailed paraphrase of his most important works, step by step
- etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of memorial papers in particular stick in my mind, from my field.

These are:

"A tribute: Professor Dr. Paul Hoffmann (March 28, 1931–July 10, 2008), a scientist with a great collaborative spirit"

and

William A. Arnold by Govindjee and Srivastava (2014)

If you can't find either of these then I'll link you to them. What sticks out for me when reading them is just how personal they are. They can go into quite a bit of family history and life history, telling some anecdotes, whilst showing happy, relaxed photographs of them. At the same time, they can cover the most important achievements of that person's scientific career.

There are plenty of examples out there for you to draw from but at the end of the day, this is your tribute to the person so make it how you think is best fitting to them and their legacy.